# Visual Studio Code Debugger (Java)

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-code, json

I keep having troubles with installing the visual studio code installer. I have the jdk-installed and I want to debug my code.

I used this tutorial. https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug

But, the code is not automatically generated inside the json.file. When I want to debug the code and generate a debug json.file. It does not work.

Here is the Json file as a code sample:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Attach)",
        "request": "attach",
        "hostName": "localhost",
        "port": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "vscode.hallo.java"
    }

]
```

}

I can't debug the code. I receive the error message convertToDto unexpected type.

Comment: I fixed it so far. I had to use code runner extension to create the debugging file. Not, via the debugger console.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is your bin path is pointing a jre. But Java Debugger requires you to use JDK instead. So the fix is changing `java.home` user setting in VS Code to your JDK home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, uninsall and reinstall the "C/C++ Extension" and than resolve the problem. (My case is occurred in C++ debuging environment)